# retrieve arraylist from AsyncTask class object after the doInBackground method is finished

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

i have classes in my projects that only does the server operations such as getting and putting data. i have class which populating list and then method to get this list. the problem is that i'm calling the "getList" method and the background operation hasent finished then i get null from the "getList" method

this is my AsyncTask class, as you can see the "getList" suppose to give me the list completed

```
public class GetRoomatesListActivity extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    private ArrayList<RoomateModel> tmpList;
    private ArrayList<RoomateModel> completeList;
    DBHelper db;
    Context context;

    public GetRoomatesListActivity(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        db = DBHelper.getInstance(context);
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        tmpList = new ArrayList<RoomateModel>();
        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);

            }
            String finalJson = buffer.toString();
            JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(finalJson);
            JSONArray parentArray = parentObject.getJSONArray("result");//creates array of Roomates of the selected apartment


            for (int i = 0; i < parentArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(i);//get the cuttent json object which is representaion of roomate object

                String Fname = finalObject.getString("firstName");
                String Lname = finalObject.getString("lastName");
                String phone = finalObject.getString("phone");

                RoomateModel item = new RoomateModel(Fname, Lname, phone);//creates roomates model with the current item data from the array
                tmpList.add(item);//adds the roomate to the list of roomates

                //add the roomates to local data base

                db.addRoomate(item,apartment);
            }

            return null;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            try {
                if (reader != null) {
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        completeList = tmpList;

    }
    public ArrayList<RoomateModel> getList(){
        return completeList;
    }

}
```

and this is the class which im trying to get the list to in order to use it but its retrieving null

```
public class roomatesScreen extends Activity {
    ListView items;
    ArrayList<RoomateModel> list; //list to compare with the list rerived from GetRoomatesListActivity
    RoomatesAdapter adapter;
    DBHelper db;
    ApartmentModel apartment;
    SharedPreferences preferences;
    GetRoomatesListActivity r;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.roomates_list);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    items = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.roomatesList);
    db = DBHelper.getInstance(this);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    int number = bundle.getInt("number");
    apartment = new ApartmentModel(number);// creates apartment model with the user's apartment number
    final String num = Integer.toString(number);
     r = new GetRoomatesListActivity(this);
    r.execute("this is the link to my query" + num);
    list = r.getList(); //here list is null
    adapter = new RoomatesAdapter(roomatesScreen.this, list);
    items.setAdapter(adapter);//here application crushes because of nullPointerExpeption
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to perform the update on UI is in PostExecute method of AsyncTask..
At the time you are accessing it, the control is in the doInBackground method. So your list is null at that time.
put this

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    super.onPostExecute(s);

    adapter = new RoomatesAdapter(roomatesScreen.this, tmpList);
    items.setAdapter(adapter);/

}
```

into the `onPostExecute()`.

**2nd solution**

Initialize the list when you are setting it to adapter. like:

```
list = new ArrayList();
```

and rest work (update the list and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on adapter object) in `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: the adapter and the items list are defined in the "RoomatesScreen" class, if i would do the "getRoomatesListActivity" inner class within the "RoomatesScreen" class it would work. but i dont

Comment: in that case you can create the constructor of your AsyncTask and pass the context and other info to update the adapter to refresh the list.

Answer (score 0):

Change doInBackground() method return type

```
public class GetRoomatesListActivity extends AsyncTask<String, String, ArrayList<Object>> {
private ArrayList<RoomateModel> tmpList;
private ArrayList<RoomateModel> completeList;
DBHelper db;
Context context;

public GetRoomatesListActivity(Context context){
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
protected ArrayList<Object> doInBackground(String... params) {

    db = DBHelper.getInstance(context);
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    tmpList = new ArrayList<RoomateModel>();
    try {
        URL url = new URL(params[0]);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();

        InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

        String line = "";

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            buffer.append(line);

        }
        String finalJson = buffer.toString();
        JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(finalJson);
        JSONArray parentArray = parentObject.getJSONArray("result");//creates array of Roomates of the selected apartment


        for (int i = 0; i < parentArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(i);//get the cuttent json object which is representaion of roomate object

            String Fname = finalObject.getString("firstName");
            String Lname = finalObject.getString("lastName");
            String phone = finalObject.getString("phone");

            RoomateModel item = new RoomateModel(Fname, Lname, phone);//creates roomates model with the current item data from the array
            tmpList.add(item);//adds the roomate to the list of roomates

            //add the roomates to local data base

            db.addRoomate(item,apartment);
        }

        return null;

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
        try {
            if (reader != null) {
                reader.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    super.onPostExecute(s);
    completeList = tmpList;

}
public ArrayList<RoomateModel> getList(){
    return completeList;
}
```

}